# What is best way to use versioning in DAC(.dacpac)?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools, database-project, dacpac

I am using database project to deploy database in continuous deployment manner as well as QA Server database deployment. But still I have lot of confusion to use the .dacpac versions?

Also, If I have .dacpac 1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0. Now I have using version 4.0 in my database, But some scenario that will I need dacpac version 3.0 on same Sql Server. Is it possible? If yes, then How can I achieve same?

Comment: You may want to snapshot your releases/versions so you can go back to them as needed. Alternatively, go back to that version in source control and build v3.  I don't think you can have the concept of 2 versions of the same database in the same database at the same time unless you're doing partial projects or something similar.

Comment: In this scenario I don`t want v4.0 (testing purpose). I have .dacpac v3.0, so I can create the schema, but some of data which is not in .dacpac v3.0 (which is inserted in .dacpac v2.0).

Comment: You may want to have your scripts be cumulative and built in such a way that they can be re-run at any point. That would solve the v2/v3 issue. Other possibility - deploy v2, then upgrade using v3. That's not ideal, but may be your best bet.